# gee-test captcha solving with playwright

Tags: puppeteer, captcha, playwright

Im trying to solve captcha for a particular site which implements gee-test Slide captcha as seen in https://www.geetest.com/en/demo
So far Ive been trying with playwright. Im trying the load the url and wait for particular selector to appear in the page and then performing the click

Problem is, Eventhough I can see the element in headful mode of playwright, playwright doesnot detect the element for some weird reason, but the xpath I use works when I run it on browser. Couldnot understand what is happening. Need some help here

Let me know what all details are needed here for better clarity. Happy to provide them